# subset a series of pandas df based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of dataframes.

```
ind = [78, 87, 677, 900]
df = pd.Series(data = [pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4), index = [0, 1, 2], columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) for _ in range(4)],
                  index = ind)
```

Each df in the series looks like this:

```
df[78]:
    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9   10  11
```

I want to get the sum of first 3 dfs in this series at column b and index 0 and column c and index 2and make a new df
so expected output would be

```
sum:
    a   b   c   d
0   0   3   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9   30  11
```

I also want to get another df which would be the sum of the first 3 dfs in the series for all values in the df

```
sum_full:
        a   b   c   d
    0   0   3   6   9
    1   12  15  18  21
    2   24  27  30  33
```

I am not sure how to subset the series based on index and get sum of only the two values thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.concat(df.head(3).tolist()).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   0   3   6   9
1  12  15  18  21
2  24  27  30  33
```

Comment: Hi what about getting only specific values in a column. Thanks

Comment: `pd.concat(df.head(3).tolist()).loc[0,'b']`

Comment: @Moshee I don't quite understand your first request.  Can you restate?

Comment: Hi. I essentially want to create another df, which sums up the values of the first three dfs in the series at column b and index 0. The rest of the values in the new created df remain the same except the value at [0, 'b'] which is three times.